# Deadlocked transactions with Hibernate on Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa, transactions

I have the following (simplified) Hibernate entities:

```
@Entity(name = "Foo")
public class Foo {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public int id;

    @OneToOne
    public Bar bar;
}
```

and,

```
@Entity(name = "Bar")
public class Bar {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public int id;

    @Column
    public String field;

    @Version
    public int version;

}
```

I update these entities in a transaction that looks roughly like this:

```
Bar bar = findBar(em);
Foo foo = findFoo(em);

bar.field = "updated value";

if (<condition>) {
    em.remove(foo);
}

em.detach(bar);
em.merge(bar);
```

Note that `em.remove(foo)` is only called sometimes, while bar is always updated.

I'm noticing occasional `ORA-00060: Deadlock detected` errors when running the application. The dump seems to suggest that the two deadlocked sessions are locked on `em.merge(bar)` and `em.remove(foo)`, but I don't understand why that would be the case.

How can this code deadlock? Is there a way to restructure it avoid deadlocking?

Here's some extra information from the trace:

```
Deadlock graph:
                       ---------Blocker(s)--------  ---------Waiter(s)---------
Resource Name          process session holds waits  process session holds waits
TX-00040005-000010dd        73    6557     X             81    6498           X
TX-00010018-000010bd        81    6498     X             73    6557           X

session 6557: DID 0001-0049-000002F5    session 6498: DID 0001-0051-0000030E 
session 6498: DID 0001-0051-0000030E    session 6557: DID 0001-0049-000002F5 

Rows waited on:
  Session 6557: obj - rowid = 00004797 - AAAEeXAB4AAADH0BBP
  (dictionary objn - 18331, file - 120, block - 12788, slot - 15)
  Session 6498: obj - rowid = 00007191 - AAAHGRAB4AAAACBBBo
  (dictionary objn - 29041, file - 120, block - 129, slot - 40)

----- Information for the OTHER waiting sessions -----
Session 6498:
program: JDBC Thin Client
    application name: JDBC Thin Client, hash value=2546894660
  current SQL:

delete from Foo where id=:1 

----- Current SQL Statement for this session (sql_id=sfasdgasdgaf) -----
update Bar set field=:1, version=:2 where id=:3 and version=:4
```

Comment: Perhaps it is really impossible to reproduce your issue. Please see this if it might help you in anyway http://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2014/02/25/understanding-oracle-deadlock/

Comment: Is it possible for you to **TRACE** the complete sessions?

Comment: @LalitKumarB I have the trace, and from that I traced it back to those calls to merge and remove. I see that those are the two locked sessions. Would you like any additional information from the trace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly the [detach](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#detach%28java.lang.Object%29) you should do something like that:

```
Foo foo = findFoo(em);
Bar bar = findBar(em);

if (<condition>) {
    em.remove(foo);
    em.detach(bar); //If it is really necessary
    em.flush();
}

bar = findBar(em); //It will reattach the entity on the persistence context
bar.field = "updated value";

em.merge(bar); 
em.commit();
```

Comment: So this ended up solving my issue. Not sure if it was due to switching the order of operation, or the explicitly flush(), detach() calls. Can you expand on when the locks are actually acquired and released within a transaction?

Comment: When you detach a entity it can not be persisted anymore (locked). Doing a find will load a new entity of the same record. This one is not detached, so you can merge without problems.

Answer (score 5):

Generally there are two main reasons for deadlock occurrence in Oracle

- so called SX to SSX lock escalation. This one is caused by missing index on FK(child table). In such a case Oracle has to lock the whole child table before validating the constrains. [See AskTom Artice](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:3932525800346405986)
- wrong order of SQL statements order

In all cases deadlock is caused by application error. You will need deadlock report(.trc file) from database server. There will you find SQL statement and tables involved. Since you use Hibernate you can hardly predict the order of SQL statement execution, sometimes it might help to extend Entity manager cache, to prevent too early calls to `flush()`.

EDITED:
OK so you have TX(X) locks. These are row level, while SSX are table level. Then the deadlocked object might be either a row in a table or a unique key in an index. The trace file should also contain previous statement for each session and also cursors(place of SQL statement execution), cursors should contain also values of bind variables.

Try to execute:

```
select * from Foo where rowid = 'AAAHGRAB4AAAACBBBo';
select * from Bar where rowid = 'AAAEeXAB4AAADH0BBP';
```

- Do you really use CamelCase for table names?
- What is DDL for "Foo" and "Bar"?
- Does deadlock occur when you drop FK between Foo and Bar?
- When you only call `em.remove(foo);` will also child Bar be removed?

Comment: I pulled this information out of a trc. I used that to trace it back to that transaction with those two entities mentioned in the question.  Are you suggesting that adding an index to the bar reference in the foo entity may resolve this?

Comment: If your deadlock report contains lock types `SX` and `SSX`, then it is the 1st case. Then you need to create an index on `FOO.BAR` as FOO is child table of BAR table. And `FOO.BAR` points into `BAR.ID`.

Comment: The deadlock trace report indicates that both of the lock types of `SX`. Neither is `SSX`

Comment: then you should update the question with trace header. Post deadlock graph, SQL statements involved, and also (possibly) their exec plans. If you can not post this information onto public site like SO, you have to contact Oracle support.

Comment: OK so you have TX(X) locks. These are row level, while SSX are table level. Then the deadlocked object might be either a row in a table or a unique key in an index.

Comment: They are using camel case. Calling `em.remove(foo)` will not remove `Bar`. Rows from `Bar` never get removed. I can try removing the FK, but that's added automatically by the Hibernate `@OneToOne` annotation, so I don't really love the idea of changing that.

Comment: Also, I can query for the Bar entity, but not the Foo one. This is because the application does retries and presumably the delete went through on a subsequent attempt.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74846/discussion-between-oleksi-and-ibre5041).